# How to get only a distinct row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which is shown on below

```
id     locale   roaming   rent
301 NULL    18.00     NULL
300 NULL    NULL      5.00
299 11.00   NULL      NULL
298 NULL    NULL      4.00
297 NULL    20.00     NULL
296 NULL    NULL      6.00
295 9.00    NULL      NULL
294 NULL    20.00     NULL
293 10.00   NULL      NULL
```

I want to get only one value in each column (without id column) in a row. How can I do it? BUT I want to do it only in one select query.

Comment: Can you show us your expected results please, along with your attempt(s)?

Comment: Your question is not deterministic (there are many solutions with different results and they all satisfy your task). One possibility is to use MAX/MIN: `select max(locale),max(roaming),max(rent) from table`

Comment: i want to get this result.

Comment: for locale 11.00 AND for roaming 18.00 AND for rent 5.00

Comment: Which SQL server version are you using?

Comment: SQL SERVER 2016

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT TOP 1 [local]
        FROM tbl
        WHERE [local] IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY [id] DESC
        ) AS [local]
    ,(
        SELECT TOP 1 [roaming]
        FROM tbl
        WHERE [roaming] IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY [id] DESC
        ) AS [roaming]
    ,(
        SELECT TOP 1 [rent]
        FROM tbl
        WHERE [rent] IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY [id] DESC
        ) AS [rent]
```

Answer (score 0):

### I do it so

DECLARE @locale AS DECIMAL(11,2)

DECLARE @roaming AS DECIMAL(11,2)

DECLARE @rent AS DECIMAL(11,2)

SELECT @locale=COALESCE(locale, @locale), @roaming=COALESCE(roaming, @roaming), @rent=COALESCE(rent, @rent) FROM my_table

SELECT @locale as locale, @roaming as roaming, @rent as rent